# if statement condition that tests for list membership is not working correctly

Tags: python, if-statement, chess, statements

I wrote a simple script, but the output is not correct. Can you give me advice how
to solve it? the question is about white or black squares on a chess board:
If I use the def with a string 'd' and int(4), it will return white, but it has
to be black?

```
def in_white(letter,integer):

    list_letters_1 = ['a','c','e','g']
    list_letters_2 = ['b','d','f','h']

    list_numbers_1 = [1,3,5,7]
    list_numbers_2 = [2,4,6,8]
    print(list_numbers_1)

    if str(letter) in list_letters_1 and int(integer) in list_numbers_1:
        print("black")
    elif str(letter) in list_letters_2 and int(integer) is list_numbers_2:
        print("black")
    else:
        print("white")

in_white('d',4)
```

Comment: `int(integer) is list_numbers_2` should be `int(integer) in list_numbers_2` is the problem

Comment: If one of these answers helped, feel free to go ahead and mark them accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This statement is the culprit:

```
elif str(letter) in list_letters_2 and int(integer) is list_numbers_2:
# ___________________________________________________^
```

That should be `in`, not `is`. You should know that `in` tests for membership, while `is` tests for equality of reference. The two are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

The line that says `elif str(letter) in list_letters_2 and int(integer) is list_numbers_2:` - The last part should be `int(integer) in list_numbers_2`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your `in` test. This line:

```
elif str(letter) in list_letters_2 and int(integer) is list_numbers_2:
```

is valid Python, but not what you meant. It should be:

```
elif str(letter) in list_letters_2 and int(integer) in list_numbers_2:
```

The `is` test will always be `False`.